# Asymptotic Distribution of Sample Quantile

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

My question is related to the proof below. Why can we say that $F^{-1}(Y_n(x))=X_{[np]}$? I would like to understand better the reason for that.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

So

Comment: The question is also asked at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178719/asymptotic-distribution-of-sample-quantile